# How to use Wordpress JSON data on a static website?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I have a Wordpress JSON link but I want to use the data on my website elsewhere...

How do I use this data? I don't think I need to parse it as it is already in an object format directly?

I am bloody useless.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp - is any of this useful as I just need to take a few blog posts and put them on a static page. It cannot be that difficult.

Comment: if you use jQuery, you can use this to read the JSON source : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: You need to parse JSON data and then use it. JSON is not a ready to use object. By the way I dont' know why you want to do that in Wordpress ;) That's not a normal practice

Comment: @gtamborero What do you mean? I just want a list of my latest posts to appear on my normal website.

Comment: You can easily do it using and jquery Ajax or getJson a useful tutorial is here : https://www.sitepoint.com/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple-example/